# playing different audios on button click Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am currently making a sort of radio switchboard.
I have all the station information in a service. I list everything in the html file after getting it through the component.

On a button click, the station url is put in an variable, which is then loaded in an audio src.
This audio source is loaded, and starts playing.

I am having some problems though putting everything in 1 button. If i load the url in the variable first with 1 button and activate with another, it works.
But when i try to put both in 1 button, it does not seem to refresh the variable.

My component:

```
   audio: any= new Audio();
    audios: any[];
    audiosource: string = '';

    //methods
    GetStation()
    {
        console.log('works');
        this.audio.src = this.audiosource;
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
    }

    //constructor
    constructor(private soundwaveService: SoundwaveService)
    {
        this.audios = soundwaveService.getStations();
    }
```

My html:

```
<div *ngFor="let audio of audios, let i = index">
    <div (click)="audiosource=audio.url">
        <button (click)="GetStation()">{{audio.station}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
--- {{audiosource}} ---
```

Comment: You want to play the `audio.url` track when the button is clicked , right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template HTML, notice that you trigger the `GetStation()` function on `click()` but you are not passing any reference to that `audio` which you want to be played. Moreover the `(click)` handler on the `div` is actually of no use.

Modify the code to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let audio of audios, let i = index">
    <div>
       <!--pass the audio you want to play in the click event's handler--> 
       <button (click)="GetStation(audio)">{{audio.station}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, in your component class:

```
  GetStation(audio)
    {
        this.audio.src = audio.src;
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
    }
```

This will play your audio track which has been clicked.

Comment: do i not have to pass on audio.url? The service contains 'station' (which is the station name) and 'url' (which has the streaming location)

Comment: Happy to help :)